# Joining Table that has no value

Tags: sql, database, join, unique

Im working on a friendship site for a client that has been built by another developer. The client has added new questions to the questions table. I can't figure out a query that will return results for all the questions, even for old users who have not answered the new questions.

The issue is that old users dont have an entry in the **user question table** so how can I get a default of 'not answer' for old users who have not input a value in the **user question table**?

See table structure below

**User Table**

```
id | username
0  | louis
```

**User Question Table**

```
ID | USERID | Question ID | Answer ID
0  | 1      | 0           | 5
1  | 1      | 1           | 8
```

**Question Table**

```
ID | QUESTION                    
0  | What is your favorite color 
1  | What is your gender         
2  | What is your favorite t.v. show
```

**Answer Table**

```
ID | answer
5  | Blue
8  | female
```

---

**This is my desired result:**

```
user       | question                        | answer
louis      | What is your favorite color     | blue
louis      | What is your gender             | female
louis      | What is your height             | Not Answered
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get all questions, left join the answers and userquestions and do a cross join with users:

```
select 
    username, 
    question, 
    answer = isnull(answer,'Not Answered')
from Question q
cross join User u 
left join UserQuestion uq on uq.QuestionID = q.ID and u.id = uq.USERID
left join Answer a on uq.AnswerID = a.ID
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c675f/2)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `cross join` to get combinations of all users and all questions.  Then use a `left join` to bring in the information about existing answers.  The final piece is `coalesce()` to substitute a value when there is no answer:

```
select u.username, q.question, coalesce(a.answer, 'Not Answered')
from user u cross join
     question q left join
     userquestion uq
     on uq.userid = u.id and
        uq.questionid = q.id left join
     answer a
     on uq.answerid = a.id
```